# Cascading timeout propagation for gRPC python

Tags: grpc, grpc-python

I'm wondering whether the cascading propagation of initial client timeout is supported by grpc-python?

I mean:

1. client performs a gRPC to server-1 with timeout = **200**ms
2. server-1 spends **110**ms to process the task and invokes server-2 for next step
3. server-2 spends **100**ms to process the task and need to invoke server-3 for next step

With timeout propagation it has no sense to call server-3 from server-2, since the total spent time is already greater than the initially set client timeout (110ms + 100ms > 200ms).

Whether such a scenarios is supported by grpc-python? 
Or it should be implemented and controlled manually?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently supported natively in gRPC Python, but I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/18358) to track this feature.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Indeed, after some tests I discovered that it doesn't work like in grpc-java, for example.